# How to use the "who ...." modifier in a 's sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to say:

> I am very jealous of a friend's success. I've known this person for over 10 years.

How can I say it in one single sentence?

Can I say something like these:

1. I am very jealous of a friend's success, who I've known for over 10 years.
2. I am very jealous of a friend who I've known for 10 years' success.

Answer (score 1):

Here the second example of:

> I am very jealous of a friend who I've known for 10 years' success.

Would sound better.

If you say:

> I am very jealous of a friend's success, who I've known for over 10 years.

People may get confused that you know "success" for 10 years.